# wso2 emm multiple tenants how to support themes

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have tested emm (enterprise mobility management), and it works well on normal situation of multiple tenants. The tenant id is designed in database. The tenant id is added to form field.  But how can I design different layout or theme for different tenant? From web structure, seems I could not figure out how to configure different themes for different tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default same EMM theme will be applied to all EMM tenants.but you can apply different theme for different EMM tenants.
for that use below the document and you can change the theme tenant wise.

[change the emm console theme](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Customizing+Themes)